# Change time format in Chart.js date

Tags: javascript, date, chart.js, momentjs

I am trying to change the date format in a Chart.js timeline chart without success, thus far, I've tried all this without success:

1. Format the date objects before adding them to the labels array:

   ```
   var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

   var date = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-EN', options);
   ```
2. Create moment objects and add them to the labels array:

   ```
   var m = moment(new Date()).format('l')
   ```

The only way that I've been able to achieve anything is by abandoning the timeline chart and build another chart where I insert formated strings representing the dates (in other words, these are simple line charts with a string as a date, but I think it's a horrible solution).

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What version of chart.js are you using?

Comment: 2.7.2 at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats

Comment: No, let me check it out please!

Comment: It's working, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the date's format in Chart.js can be as easy as this:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                displayFormats: {
                    quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

})

You can replace the format in `displayFormats` with any of the names giving in the formating table in [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats).

Comment: Btw your first solution did not work, I believe, because it is more on the  display of the javascript date objects.